# Masonry pictures overlay and does not inline correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-masonry

I have the following Css,Javascript and Html:

```
/* fluid 5 columns */
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item { 
    width: 20%; 
}
/* 2 columns */
.grid-item--width2 { 
    width: 40%; 
}
```

JS:

```
    // init Masonry
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
    // set itemSelector so .grid-sizer is not used in layout
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    // use element for option
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    percentPosition: true
});
// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
<!-- width of .grid-sizer used for columnWidth -->
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
<div class="grid-item">
    <img src="img/frontpage/girl.jpg"alt="recent project">
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
    <img src="img/frontpage/mid.png">
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see the images overlay eachother instead of inline correctly.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: How about a Link or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use your bigger grid item class, .grid-item--width2 (I can't load masonry but the html will show you what I mean):

```js
    // init Masonry
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
    // set itemSelector so .grid-sizer is not used in layout
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    // use element for option
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    percentPosition: true
});
// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

```css
/* fluid 5 columns */
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item { width: 20%; }
/* 2 columns */
.grid-item--width2 { width: 40%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.0.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
<!-- width of .grid-sizer used for columnWidth -->
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
<div class="grid-item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"alt="recent project">
</div>
<div class="grid-item--width2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey use this Css only layout:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="columns">
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://www.strangenotions.com/wp-content/uploads/nature_clouds_heaven_019281_.jpeg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor s </a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://2.everystudent.com/pics4/heaven2.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 2 - dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://llerrah.com/images5/heavensgrocerystoretop.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 3 - nt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut </a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://www.camerondobbins.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/heaven.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 4 - nt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua & nt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://www.strangenotions.com/wp-content/uploads/nature_clouds_heaven_019281_.jpeg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor s </a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://2.everystudent.com/pics4/heaven2.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 2 - dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://llerrah.com/images5/heavensgrocerystoretop.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 3 - nt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut </a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://www.camerondobbins.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/heaven.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 4 - nt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua & nt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://www.strangenotions.com/wp-content/uploads/nature_clouds_heaven_019281_.jpeg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor s </a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://2.everystudent.com/pics4/heaven2.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 2 - dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://llerrah.com/images5/heavensgrocerystoretop.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 3 - nt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut </a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://www.camerondobbins.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/heaven.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <h3 class="extra-bold">
                <a href="#">Heaven 4 - nt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua & nt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
            <br>

            <div class="vertical-space-sm"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 12;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 12;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 12;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-fill: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 965px) {
    #columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;

    -moz-column-count: 4;

    column-count: 4;

    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;

    -moz-column-count: 2;

    column-count: 2;

    }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;

    -moz-column-count: 1;

    column-count: 1;

    }
}
.pin {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin: 0 2px 15px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.pin img {
    width: 100%;
}

.pin p {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}
```